# how to solve positioning problem of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

this is my html and css code right now

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10"></div>
    <div class="col-1 dropdown">
      <button class="btn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Menu
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Education</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hobbies</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.header{
position: relative;
top: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
min-width: 120px !important;
height: 145px !important;
position: relative;
right: 0;
}

body {
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

i want to make it so that the dropdown menu is shifted to the right instead of the left [what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSTY8.png)
but what i got with my code was this [what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jljbJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any custom css for this if you are using bootstrap.

> By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the top and along the left side of its parent. Add .dropdown-menu-right to a .dropdown-menu to right align the dropdown menu.

Refer: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7aso841L/

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-10"></div>
      <div class="col-1 dropdown">
        <button class="btn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Menu
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Education</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hobbies</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```